# Setting the rating of the Android Ratingbar

Tags: android

So I'm trying to set the rating of the RatingBar (RB) widget in code during a touch event. Basically, when a user clicks the RB, it has to do some background stuff and then the value of the RB should obviously display the new value.

Okay let me also state that I'm using the RB as a "favourite" button. It's probably not the best thing to use but that doesn't mean I can't, right?

The RB consists of only 1 star. And if a user clicks it, it adds an item to the favourites list and highlights the star. When the user clicks it again, sure enough, the item is removed from the favourites list but the RB does not reset to 0.

```
favourite_button.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    if (_favourited) {
      // do stuff
      favourite_button.setRating(0);
      _favourited = false;
    } else {
      // do stuff
      favourite_button.setRating(1);
      _favourited = true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}});
```

My code works, and it works well, I just can't see why "unfavouriting" doesn't change the RB back to 0.

So what could be the problem? When I use "setRating(0)" in a setOnRatingBarChangeListener it sure enough sets the rating to 0. But I can't use the setOnRatingBarChangeListener of the RB because one can't "touch" zero stars.

how to set it back to 0 when clicked again?

Comment: To do a "favorite star" is hundred times better to use an ImageButton with a two star resources, one to be set when it's not favorite and one when it is.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I'm still puzzled as to why this is happening. In all honest truth, why shouldn't I be able to use the RatingBar for this purpose? I agree the widget wasn't designed for that purpose but I should still be able to use it in such I way. Sorry, I'm not trying to be an a'hole about this, I just want to know why this is happening. @Fondesa thanks for the comment though. :)

Comment: Simply because to unset the rating bar the user hasn't to click on it but to slide from right to left from official documentation. If you have only one star you can't slide because the space is too low.

Comment: Oh I see, you're right. It's actually extended from the SeekBar. Thanks. I get why this is happening. Also, I've decided to use the ToggleButton. Works mush better for this purpose. Thank you @Fondesa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Fondesa has pointed out to me as to why you can't set the rating to 0 in the OnTouch event.

The RatingBar is extended from the SeekBar and the listener actually expects a slide action. Thus the RB can't be set to 0 (or not for this purpose) when there is only one star. The proper widget to use for this type of functionality (no surprise here) is the ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using on `onTouchListener`, you should register an `OnRatingBarChangeListener`. This way, you don't have to worry yourself with the implementation of detecting a touch event and whether that should affect the rating bar, all you need worry about is if the rating was changed:

```
favourite_button.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            _favourited = rating > 0;
        }
    });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html

That all being said, I assume you're doing more than just setting a boolean. If you're not, you should just get rid of the boolean completely, and whenever you actually need the value, you can just call `favourite_button.getRating()`

Comment: Yes I tried this at first, being the go to listener one should use when using a RatingBar. This is the right implementation to use, I'll agree to that.

Comment: But. What my question specifically was, was that one couldn't "uncheck" so to speak, a RatingBar. Initially it is set to a rating of 0, right? My question was, why can't the RatingBar be set to 0 by the user after he has set it to, say 1 star?

Comment: So I tried many things, and it was stupid of me to try and use a single star RatingBar as a "favourite" button. The RatingBar is extended from the SeekBar. It is meant to use movement actions too.